# Combine multiple JSON values as one variable

Tags: jquery, json

Currently I'm working on my assignment which wanted me to get a value from two JSON results. Here is where I am stuck:

1) I have 2 JSON URLs which both return different values:

```
    function AA(){
        $.getJSON("url1.js", function(VALUEA){
        VALUEA.json;
        });
    }
    function BB(){
        $.getJSON("url2.js", function (VALUEB){
        VALUEB.json;
        });
    }
```

2) Then, I need to combine both results and do some math in jQuery:

```
function MATH() { 
RESULT = VALUEB.json / VALUEA.json;
alert(RESULT); }
```

I can parse both JSON results but it failed to combine in the MATH function. What should I do in order to make it work?

Thanks :|

Comment: can we have a look on the format url1.js and url2.js returns ?

Comment: Also, is your MATH function just going to find the quotient?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are using two getJSON calls which are Asynchronous calls. This means that while the getJson runs the calling function finishes what it needs to do and the program doesn't need to wait for the results of getJSON to run.So when you run your MATH function there isn't a guarentee that both getJSON calls have completed. Without knowing how your AA and BB functions are called I would suggest if possible to nest the two get JSON calls and the MATH function call to get the proper answer.

```
function AA(){
    $.getJSON("url1.js", function(VALUEA){
       BB();
    });
}
function BB(){
    $.getJSON("url2.js", function (VALUEB){
    MATH();
    });
}
function MATH() { 
    RESULT = int(VALUEB.json.yourVar) / int(VALUEA.json.yourVar);
    alert(RESULT); }
```

EDIT: Removed part of answer that caused an infinite loop. Sorry it was a really brain dead answer that I should have thought better of before posting. I still stand by the above though.

Comment: Javascript is not a multithreaded language, so this loop will run once or infinitely.

Comment: Thanks BiAiB for pointing that out. Even if JS was multi-threaded the second part of my answer wouldn't have given the desired results. Don't really know what was going through my head when I typed it out.

Comment: your solution work but cause the system to wait for consecutive calls. It could seem to be unimportant, but believe me, I'm working on a project that make dozens of calls like this, And it takes forever to load. In a version I rewrite with parallel, the time needed to load went from 15-20seconds to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax calls, as their name state, are asynchronous. So first you need to "synchronize" them to perform the math, ie you have to wait both of them have loaded before you do your math.

To do so, put in your callback function some call to a checker function that will check if the two ajax calls ended, and if so perform the math.

Here's how to do it:

```
var valueA, valueB;

function checkIfEverythinIsFine() {
    if ( (valueA || valueA === 0) && (valueB || valueB === 0) )
        Math();
}

function AA(){
    $.getJSON("url1.js", function(VALUEA){
        valueA = VALUEA.json;
        checkIfEverythinIsFine()
    });
}
function BB(){
    $.getJSON("url2.js", function (VALUEB){
        valueB =VALUEB.json;
        checkIfEverythinIsFine()
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry for the (valueA || valueA === 0), I don't know the isNumber function in jQuery

Comment: You can do a regular expression test to see if a number by something similar to : /^d+$/.test(valueA);

Comment: both answer not working for me. just upload actual format for url1.js and url2.js

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. Ok here is my actual code.

```
function totalcss(){
$.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.js?q=css&callback=?", function (valuecss){
var css = valuecss.response.a;
}); }
```

Second value is

```
function totaljquery(){
$.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.js?q=jquery&callback=?", function (valuejquery){
var css = valuejquery.response.a;
}); }
```

Then my math is to get percentage for both,

> var totalsearch = (valuecss +
>   valuejqeury);
>
> var css_percentage = valuecss /
>   totalsearch * 100
>
> var jquery_percentage = valuejquery /
>   totalsearch * 100

I believe is the matter of asynchronous issue but ive got no idea how to make it work. :(